# Прописать сопоставление IP адрес - доменное имя для приложения

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dns

Есть ли возможность для своего разрабатываемого приложения вручную указать сопоставление IP адрес - сайт, подобно файлу host на Windows или Linux? Чтобы приложение подключалось к нужному серверу в обход DNS?

Comment: Матрица строк 2хКоличество алиасов. В первом столбце адрес, во втором его сопоставление. Перед подключением ищете адрес в первом столбце, а подключаетесь по адресу из второго.

Comment: далеко не всегда возможно. Если на одном ip хостится несколько сайтов, помимо указания вместо имени - адреса (например - https://151.101.129.69/ - это ru.stackoverflow.com, по крайней мере - один из его адресов) требуется ещё в заголовке http-запроса правильно указать - к какому сайту по этому ip идет обращение

Comment: Это нужно для указания адреса бэкенда в retrofit2. Как можно в настройках retofit указать IP + host?

Comment: в самом ретрофите в качестве url указываете IP, а в хедеры добавляете хедер Host с "настоящим" именем хоста (,без http и слешей). Но может Ваш сервер "наивен" и получится просто по айпи обратится